# Shopify Account Activation Link (Redirect or Email)

Tags: shopify

I am currently working on customizing a store for a customer using shopify. The problem that i REALLY need your guys help with involves Shopify Customer Signup method.

The store has two ways a customer can enter email address. Either he/she can signup the newsletter or can register with the store.

Register with the store is going all fine but what we need to so is that when a user inputs email for newsletter registration two things should happen:

1. The newsletter form should take the user (redirects him) to the Account Activation page that asks for passwords.
2. And it also should send the user the account activation email to the input address.

I just need a start up on how to get this done as i am new to shopify and i am stuck here. I do know that there is a field that needs to be turned true but i have even tried that as follows in the newsletter form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer[send_email_invite]" value="true" />
```

Kindly help me out here.

Regards,

Maddy

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the shopify tag {{ customer.account_activation_url }} into an email that doesn't come from Shopify. Registering in a newsletter will connect to a third party mailer like Mailchimp, right?

To achieve this, you need a custom app that connects with the Shopify API.